# Integrate NopCommerce 3.x with existing asp.net web form application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration, nopcommerce

I have an existing website developed with ASP.net Webform .net 4.0 version. Now we need to integrate NopCommerce 3.7 version in that same site.  (We do not want SSO OR two different subdomain).

How can we setup this in single existing .net site.

Thanks

Comment: if you going to merge two applications into one solution, then it's a long way. you need to update your existing .net framework to version 4.5.1, update the library and etc.

Comment: how do you want to integrate them? Nopcommerce already gives you all possible option that a shop needs. If you already have a shop on webforms and you arent happy with it, you should consider switching completely to NopCommerce. only challenge here is adopting your existing DB on NC DB. rest is there anyway. any other missing function, you can find either a plugin or program your own plugin. It is very easy to program plugin once you learn the trick.